# XSLT Duplicate Templates with Includes

Tags: visual-studio-2008, xslt

I'm having a problem with including xslt templates.

I have a.xslt which includes b.xslt and c.xslt.

b and c both require a template located in d.xslt.  If I add the include statement in b and c, I get a duplicate template error in VS2008:

```
The named template 'MyTemplate' does not exist.
```

and when I try to hit the web page that uses these XSLTs I get an error and they don't display correctly.

If I include d.xslt in a.xslt it will display correctly, but I get an error in b and c stating that the template I'm referencing doesn't exist:

```
'MyTemplate' is a duplicate template name.
```

What would be the correct way to have this kind of include tree?  Or maybe it's just a VS2008 problem?

I could eliminate d.xslt and add that template to both b and c, but it's easier to manage if the template is in one place.

- edited:  Added actual VS2008 error text.

Comment: I don't know what a *duplicate template error* is...

Comment: @Alejandro: Edited to include the actual text of the VS2008 errors

Comment: `'MyTemplate' is a duplicate template name.` That changes all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `xsl:include` is the same as pasting them all in one giant file, which would also give you the same duplicate template errors.

**Use `xsl:import` instead of `xsl:include`**.
It will overlay/merge all of the templates to give you a super-set.  The last template in the import chain will "win" instead of giving you a duplicate definition error, as it will have higher precedence.

- Have a.xslt `xsl:import` b.xslt and c.xslt.
- Have b.xslt and c.xslt `xsl:include` or `xsl:import` d.xslt.

Personally, I tend to always use `xsl:import` over `xsl:include`.

The only real downside of `xsl:import` is that you might accidentally override a template further down in the import chain and not know it(because you won't get the same compilation error that you would with `xsl:include`).  There might be a slight performance hit, since the XSLT processor has to "think" a little more about the import chain, but I haven't found that to be a problem.

Comment: I don't think this is a correct answer, actually. At best it's a workaround to cope with VS2008 limitations. It's true that if B and C both import D, you won't get a problem with duplicates, but it's not good practice to import the same templates with multiple precedences, and it shouldn't be necessary. It should work correctly if (for example) A includes B,C, and D, and B and C contain no includes.

Comment: @Michael Kay - Why is it bad practice? Shouldn't the import precedence ensure that the "top level" declaration "wins"? What about having B and C *include* D and then have A *import* B and C?  Would that be a little better practice? If one wanted B and C to work independent of A, it is convenient to have those sort of include/import chains.

Comment: I agree with the "use `xsl:import` instead `xsl:include`" recomendation. But do note that **there is no restriction in the spec other than not include itself**.

Answer (score 1):

IDEs such as VS2008 tend to believe when you are editing a stylesheet document that it must be complete, that is, taken together with the things it includes/imports, all names must resolve. In fact this is not the case according to the XSLT language; when A includes B it's quite legal for components in B to refer to components in A even though B does not include A. I believe oXygen has a switch somewhere that allows you to control this. XSLT allows cyclic includes, but they can cause problems with some processors.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#named-templates

> It is an error if a stylesheet
>   contains more than one template with
>   the same name and same [import
>   precedence](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-import-precedence).

This also shows that the `xsl:import` mechanism is better than the inclusion (in most of the cases) and it should be see as the inheritance mechanism between transformations.